# Doubt in tensor calculus in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

I am stuck in the derivation of $G$ (Einstein tensor) in the condition of weak field ($h$ small) where $g_{\alpha\beta}=\eta_{\alpha\beta}+h_{\alpha\beta}$ and $h^{\alpha\beta}=\bar{h}^{\alpha\beta}-\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\bar{h}.$
I calculated the Ricci tensor:

$$R_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\bar{h}{^{\mu}}_{\beta,\alpha\mu}+\bar{h}{_{\alpha\mu,}}{^\mu}_{\beta}-\bar{h}{_{\alpha\beta,}}{^\mu}_{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\alpha\beta}\bar{h}{^\lambda}{_\lambda,}{^\mu}_\mu\right)$$

and I now should calculate the Ricci scalar to get $G_{\alpha\beta} = R_{\alpha\beta} - \frac{1}{2} g_{\alpha\beta} R$.

So

$$R = g^{\alpha \beta}R_{\alpha \beta} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\bar{h}{^{\mu\nu}}_{,\nu\mu}+\bar{h}{_{\nu\mu,}}{^{\mu\nu}}_{}-\bar{h}{_{\nu\,}}{^{\nu}},^{\mu}_{\mu}+\bar{h}{^\lambda}{_\lambda,}{^\mu}_\mu\right).$$

I know the result should be $R = \bar{h}_{\mu\nu,}{^{\mu\nu}}+\frac{1}{2}\bar{h}{^\lambda}{_\lambda,}{^\mu}_\mu$ but I really can't figure out how to do the calculus in the right way. (I'm very new to tensor calculus.) I know I did some errors in the contraction of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ but I don't undertand why.

Comment: Did you assume that $\eta^{\alpha\beta}\eta_{\alpha\beta}$ is$1$? It isn’t.

Comment: You have an incorrect factor of 1/2. The Ricci scalar is just the contraction of the Ricci tensor, not 1/2 of it.

Comment: @G.Smith 1/2  is there , but I don't understand how to work out the last formula for $R$. Did I do any mistake in the contraction of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: *Can someone find the error?* Check-my-work questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: *Did I do any mistake in the contraction of  and ?* Yes, at least one, and  I pointed it out in my first comment.

Comment: And when you added two 1/2’s, one of them was wrong.

Comment: @Jatos Do $\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}=\eta^{00}\eta_{00}+\eta^{11}\eta_{11}+\eta^{22}\eta_{22}+\eta^{33}\eta_{33}=?$ by hand and you will see it is not equal to 1.

Comment: Ah okay . Thank you

Comment: @NDewolf I believe any terms past first order are being neglected, so since there is already a factor of $\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}$ in there, only the Minkowski term survives.

Comment: @JohnDumancic I had misread the point. What i said was completely unnessary for the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\partial_\mu\partial_\nu A^{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\alpha\mu}\eta_{\beta\nu}\partial^\alpha\partial^\beta A^{\mu\nu}=\partial^\mu\partial^\nu A_{\mu\nu}$, upon renaming indexes on the last step. By similar reasoning, $A^\mu_{\;\,\mu}=A_{\mu}^{\;\,\mu}$ Also, note that $\eta^{\mu\nu}\eta_{\mu\nu}=\delta^\mu_{\mu}=4$, so the last term should be $2\partial^\mu\partial_\mu h^\nu_{\;\,\nu}$. Correcting and using the identities, we have

$$
\begin{align}
R &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\partial^\mu\partial^\nu\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}+\partial^\mu\partial^\nu\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}-\partial^\mu\partial_\mu\bar{h}^\nu_{\;\,\nu}+2\partial^\mu\partial_\mu \bar{h}^\nu_{\;\,\nu}\right) \\
&=\partial^\mu\partial^\nu\bar{h}_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\partial_\mu \bar{h}^\nu_{\;\,\nu}
\end{align}
$$
as expected.